# 'fatal: unable to fork' when trying to push to the same repository using CircleCI

Tags: github, continuous-integration, circleci

I have a static page generator written in Hakyll in my repo's `hakyll` branch and I'm trying to configure CircleCI to generate the page on the `master` branch whenever I commit changes to the `hakyll` branch. Currently, my CircleCI config file looks like this

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: fpco/stack-build:lts
    steps:
      - checkout
      - add_ssh_keys:
          fingerprints:
            - "$$:$$:$$:...:$$"
      - run:
          name: Resolve/Update Dependencies
          command: stack setup
      - run:
          command: stack build --dependencies-only
      - run:
          name: Build Site App
          command: stack build --pedantic
      - run:
          name: Generate Static Site
          command: stack exec site build
      - run:
          name: Publish GitHub Pages
          command: |
            REMOTE_URL=$(git config --get remote.origin.url)
            cd ./_site
            # initalize repo
            git init
            git config user.name  'CircleCI'
            git config user.email 'job@circleci.com'
            # add generated files
            git add .
            git commit -m "publish $CIRCLE_SHA1 [ci skip]"
            # push to pages branch
            echo "Add remote: $REMOTE_URL"
            git remote add origin "$REMOTE_URL"
            echo "About to push"
            git push --force origin master
```

Basically, the generated page is stored on the `_site` folder and I'm trying to commit its contents to the root of the `master` branch by initializing a new git repo with the project's url as a remote. I then commit the contents of `_site` to the master branch.

I have already added a read/write Deploy Key to my Github project and CircleCI 'SSH Permitions'. The key's fingerprint is used in place of 
"$$:$$:$$:...:$$" in the above script.

However, anytime I push something to the `hakyll` branch, the job fails in the last `git push` with the message

> fatal: unable to fork
>
> Exited with code 128

Did I screw up some step? Note that I'm running on a private repository

Comment: Did you install `openssh` service like `openssh-client`?